# Pointers with multiple asterisk?

Tags: c++, pointers

When declaring a pointer variable,  is there ever a use for more than one asterisk? I know when you want to have a pointer point to another you would use multiple, but just to clarify,  when declaring you still only put one?

Comment: A pointer to a `int*` is a `int**`. A `int*` can't point to a `int*`. If you feel the need to use two stars, you should take a moment to reconsider your design. If you feel the need to use three or more stars, you may be a [three star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) (spoiler : that's not a good thing).

Comment: Yes, you can use as many asterisk as you want, however you should consider not to do so, otherwise you may turn into [three star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer).

Comment: As you are using C++, why are you even using raw pointers?

Comment: Linked lists can be a lot easier to navigate with pointers to pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Weard things: an example of 3 asterisks:

```
const char **stringArray;
```

now, if you want to allocate this array in a function as an argument, you need the following:

```
void stringAllocator(const char ***stringArray, int size) {
     *stringArray = (const char **) malloc(size);
}

...
stringAllocator (&stringArry, 20);
...
```

So, you can imagine more than 3 as well, though i had never saw more than  4 :-)

an a bit weirder stuff in c++ using stars in combination with `&`

```
void stringAllocator(const char **&stringArray, int size) {
     stringArray = (const char **) malloc(size);
}

...
stringAllocator (stringArry, 20);
...
```

In the above case works as a star reduction technique. It does the same as the first examle

Answer (score 0):

> When declaring a pointer variable, is there ever a use for more than one asterisk?

Sure, there are uses for declarations of pointer to pointer variables.

Let's suppose you have a function that does allocate some class instance internally, but needs to indicate failure at the same time. You can give it a signature like

```
   bool CreateSomeType(SomeType** pointerToSomeTypePointer) {
       try {
           *pointerToSomeTypePointer = new SomeType();
       }
       catch(...) {
           return false;
       }
       return true;
   }
```

and being called like this

```
   SomeType* ptr = nullptr;

   if(CreateSomeType(&ptr)) {
      // Use ptr
      // ...
      delete ptr;
   }
   else {
      // Log failure
   }
```

Comment: This is more useful for foreign function interfaces than classic C++ code, where you could just return `std::unique_ptr<SomeType>`, with NULL indicating failure.

Comment: @Ben Be assured, I of course wouldn't use that for production code. Just to demonstrate the use case for pointers to pointers.

Answer (score 0):

A common use case of two stars is when a function has to alter a pointer value, e.g. in ADT implementations like "Stack".
Though this design is more C than C++ (in C++ you can use other mechanisms like references), see the following example. I wrote it in "C"-style (even if you mentioned C++):

```
struct node {
  int x;
  struct node* next;
};

// this one works:
void insertBeforeHead(node** head, int value) {
  struct node* newNode = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  newNode->next = *head;
  newNode->x = value;
  *head = newNode;  // alters the pointer value of the caller
}

// this one does not work:
void insertBeforeHead2(node* head, int value) {
  struct node* newNode = (struct node*)malloc(new Node);
  newNode->next = head;
  newNode->x = value;
  head = newNode;  // alters only the local copy of the pointer value
}

int main () {

  struct node* mainHead = NULL;
  insertBeforeHead(&mainHead,10);  // changes the value of mainHead
  insertBeforeHead2(mainHead,20); // does not change the value of mainHead, althouth it should.
}
```